# How to print string characters in separate lines in assembly language?

Tags: assembly

This is one of the codes provided but i want the output to look something like this

```
"
A
B
C
.
.
.
Z
"
```

provided code:

```
 .MODEL SMALL
 .STACK 100H

 .DATA
 PROMPT  DB  'The Upper Case Letters from A to Z are: $'

 .CODE
   MAIN PROC
     MOV AX, @DATA                ; initialize DS 
     MOV DS, AX

     LEA DX, PROMPT               ; load and print PROMPT 
     MOV AH, 9
     INT 21H

     MOV CX, 26                   ; initialize CX

     MOV AH, 2                    ; set output function  
     MOV DL, 65                   ; set DL with A

     @LOOP:                       ; loop start
       INT 21H                    ; print character

       INC DL                     ; increment DL to next ASCII character

       DEC CX                     ; decrement CX

     JNZ @LOOP                    ; jump to label @LOOP if CXis 0

     MOV AH, 4CH                  ; return control to DOS
     INT 21H
   MAIN ENDP
 END MAIN
```

Comment: Have you tried to print after each character, the chars for Carriage Return and Line Feed? ASCII CODES: (0Dh, 0Ah)

Answer (score 1):

If you will check ASCII table, you will see there are some special characters.
In DOS the character sequence for new line with `int 21h` functions is 13, 10.

Thus you can either modify `dl` to go trough letter -> int 21h, then store it somewhere, load it with 13 + int 21h, load it with 10 + int 21h, restore dl to letter.

Or create a string containing `linestring db 'A', 13, 10, '$'` in .data, and keep printing (ah=9, int 21h) this line 26 times, with incrementing `inc byte ptr [linestring]` (incrementing the first `'A' == 65` byte).

---

OR if you would be still in age of DOS and doing something serious, you would drop the whole `int 21h` and you would simply update video ram at `b800:0000` directly. As that was *much* more quicker in terms of performance.

But in 80x25 text mode you can't fit all 26 letters at single screen, so the question is how you want your output to look (maybe you want to set first some text mode with more lines?).

Like example:

```
    ... some init?
    mov   ax,0B800h
    mov   es,ax
    xor   di,di     ; es:di = upper left corner of text mode video ram
    mov   ax,0A00h + 'A'  ; light green color on black, 'A' letter
    mov   cx,25     ; only 25 letters will fit on screen in 80x25 mode
lineLoop:
    mov   es:[di],ax
    add   di,80*2   ; next line is 80*2 (2 bytes per character, 80 chars width)
    inc   al        ; next letter
    dec   cx
    jnz   lineLoop
    ... exit to DOS
```